# Magento Onestep checkout

Tags: magento

I would like to add a custom field under the billing information tab of magento onestep checkout. Does any one know how i could get this done. I am pretty much new to magento

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on what you want to do with this custom field: Is this part of a payment method? Then extend that payment method, add the field to the template for said module and later on save the attribute in the model.